# How to block jQuery file from showing if the url is typed directly in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp

Let's say I have a application with jQuery running in a local server. Eg.localhost:8080/app/test.html

If a user changes the url and enters localhost:8080/app/js/jQuery-1.4.4.min.js, they are able to see the jQuery file.

How to block the file from showing if the url is typed directly in the browser ?

Comment: Short answer: *whatever* you do, there will be a way around it.  The browser needs to be able to read that file, and if the browser can read it then a person can read it - either directly or just by looking at what the browser has already loaded

Comment: Hi @free Thanks for your comment,I just need it to blocked from the url path, any other way of reading it is not a issue.

Comment: Rename it to `jquery-not-standard.js` then they can't load it from `jquery-1.4.4.min.js`.   More useful would be to configure your server not to serve js files then have your application serve them only if provides a changing parameter eg `...jquery.js?id=xxx` then users will need that parameter to get the file - your app knows the parameter and if it changes (eg base-64-encode the date+time) then it becomes *slightly* harder to get; never impossible.